# Execute shell script in SBT task through SSH

Tags: ssh, sbt

Couldn't find any info on this, is that possible? I just need to execute run little command like `systemctl restart project` after publish task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do this in [my tests](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/sbt-test/debian/java-app-archetype/build.sbt#L31-L36).  However, there's some odd output things in there to catch failures.

The basic gist is that sbt provides a [process API](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Process.html) which eventualyl became part of Scala's core library.

Here's an example:

```
val restartSystemService = taskKey[Unit]("restarts stuff")

restartSystemService := {
  val logger = streams.value.log
  Process("systemctrl restart project") ! logger match {
    case 0 => // Success!
    case n => sys.error(s"Could not restart the project, exit code: $n")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i've found a small library - [scala-ssh](https://github.com/sirthias/scala-ssh), to make it available in `.scala` build definition we need to add this dependency into `project/build.sbt` file so we can define such tasks:

```
val restart = taskKey[Unit]("restart")

restart := {
  SSH(host, config) { client =>
    client.exec("systemctl restart project")
  }
}
```